# How can python generate Dorpbox auth tokens after expire?

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, dropbox

In  my python website, I added dropbox refresh token, App key and Secret key. And in settings.py file I generate access token from these details.
Now, my question is that how it will get new auth token after refresh token after expire it . Settings.py loads only one time when build is done and project starts. after expire token, it giving errors.

Answer (score 0):

Apps using the Dropbox API can get long-term access by requesting "offline" access, in which case the app receives a "refresh token" that can be used to automatically retrieve new short-lived access tokens as needed, without further manual user intervention. The refresh tokens themselves do not expire.

The Dropbox SDKs can handle this automatically for you. For the official [Dropbox Python SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python), you can find examples of this flow at the following links:

- https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/main/example/oauth/commandline-oauth-scopes.py
- https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/main/example/oauth/commandline-oauth-pkce.py

Otherwise, if you're not using a Dropbox SDK, refer to the following resources for information on how to implement this process in your code:

- https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide
- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization
- https://dropbox.tech/developers/using-oauth-2-0-with-offline-access